# How to prove a result about the accumulation point / cluster point in Brownian Motion?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, probability-theory, random-variables

I have a standard Brownian motion, $B(t)$, $t\ge0$.

I am trying to prove the following result:

Every $t > 0$ is an accumulation point (i. e., cluster point) of $(s: B(s) = B(t))$ from the right, with probability $1$.

That is, I would like to prove that, for any fixed $t > 0,$

$P[$inf$(s > t : B(s) = B(t)) = t] = 1$

I am new to analysis and preparing for finals that's scheduled for next week.  Any insight or advice on this proof will be very helpful.  Thanks a lot!

$EDIT:$

I have a follow-up question that kind of takes off from the above, and is posted here:  [Proof regarding cluster point in Brownian motion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821241/proof-regarding-cluster-point-in-brownian-motion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, here are a couple of hints.

Hint #1:  Consider the process $X(t)=B(1/t), t>0$.  This process is very interesting.  Like $B$, it has independent increments each with zero-mean Gaussian distribution.  It would practically be a Brownian motion itself, except its variance is all wrong. We have $E(X^2(t))=E(B^2(1/t)) = 1/t$, but if we scaled $X(t)$ by an appropriate deterministic function of $t$, it would meet all the criteria of a Brownian motion.  Studying its behavior for large $t$ may tell you something about the behavior of $B$ for small $t$.

Hint #2: If a scaled version of $X(t)$ was a Brownian  motion, it would be recurrent at $x=0$, so it would visit $x=0$ infinitely often for arbitrarily large times.  Relate this back to the behavior of $B$ at arbitarily small times.  Apply the fact that the behavior of $B(s), s\geq0$ is the same as the behavior of $B(s+t)-B(t), s\geq0$ for any fixed $t>0$.

Comment: By the way, this $1/t$ trick is a standard technique, and you've hopefully seen it before.  If not, don't feel bad about not coming up with it yourself -- you'd need to be some kind of analysis prodigy to figure it out independently.

Comment: Thank you so much for these hints!  I am just learning about time reversal in Brownian motion now.  I have only seen time reversal in Markov chains earlier.  Your hints helped me work out that if we take $Y(t) = t X(t) = t B(1/t),$ then $Y(t)$ will be a standard Brownian motion!  Then it follows that $B(t)$ visits $0$ infinitely often over any interval of time, no matter how small.  So for every $\epsilon$ $> 0$, there exist times $s$ in $(t, t+\epsilon)$ such that $B(s) = B(t)$.  This hopefully completes the proof.  Thank you so much once again for your helpful insight!

Comment: Hello again! I have a follow-up question.  Instead of a fixed $t > 0,$ suppose I consider all $t \in [0, 1]$.  In this case, I wonder whether a similar logic as above holds for $P[$inf$(s > t : B(s) = B(t)) = t$ for all $t \in [0, 1]] =$ $1$.  So essentially, is $P[$inf$(s > t : B(s) = B(t)) = t$ for all $t \in [0, 1]] =$ $1$ ?  I think no, but again I am stuck trying to prove it rigorously.  Would you have any advice on how I can approach this?  Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: It might be better to post your edit as a separate question, but I think you're on the right track.  Consider a fixed $\omega$ -- you only need to find one $\omega$-dependent time $T(\omega)$ that isn't an accumulation point from the right to prove $\omega$ is not in the event "all $t\in[0,1]$ are accumulation points from the right".  I think "the last time $B(t)=0$" would work for almost all $\omega$.

Comment: Thank you for your time!  I have edited the post and posted a separate question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821241/proof-regarding-cluster-point-in-brownian-motion